# Appending postfix string to result of select query in Greenplum database

Tags: sql, greenplum

I have a table like the following in Greenplum

| Name | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| George_Henry_CLASS_3 | 94 |
| Jhon | 72 |
| Michael | 59 |
| David_Warner_CLASS_4 | 88 |

I want to append CLASS_5 string to each of the name in this table. If name already has CLASS_4 or CLASS_3 it should be replaced with CLASS_5 using select query. We can append string in select query like below.

`select Name||'CLASS_5', Marks from student`

How to replace already existing "CLASS_X" ? I want to have end result table as below.

| Name | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| George_Henry_CLASS_5 | 94 |
| Jhon_CLASS_5 | 72 |
| Michael_CLASS_5 | 59 |
| David_Warner_CLASS_5 | 88 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Name LIKE'%CLASS%' THEN
            REGEXP_REPLACE(Name,'CLASS_\d','CLASS_5')
            ELSE Name || '_CLASS_5'
       END AS Name,
       Marks
FROM student;
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rWd_Fk5_) on Postgres.